# how to share folders with a windows 10 host and a mac guest?

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox, shared-folders

I am running VirtualBox in my Windows 10 and The guest os is Mac Mojave.
In VirtualBox, in the setting of Mac Mojave, sharedFolders [shared folders in virtual box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQlaI.png), I added some folders, but can't find them in the mac OS. I searched in 'Finder' but found nothing!
So if I can't share folders in this way! how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: @Tetsujin Who says it's non-Apple hardware? You can run Windows 10 on a Mac.

Comment: @snips-n-snails - Can you really imagine someone is going to go to all the trouble to try running a Mac VM on top of Windows under Boot Camp? Why on earth would you, when running a Win VM on Mac is simplicity itself & hits no licensing issues at all?

Comment: @Tetsujin Are there really licensing issues with running a Mac VM under Windows on Apple hardware?

Comment: @snips-n-snails - none 'legally', because it's Apple hardware - but you still have to start with a hooky implementation, as no-one legitimately makes a macOS VM that can run on Windows. It's all a bit [Heath Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson)/[Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg) done that way round ;)